# Perdi arquivos com extensão .java

Tags: java

Bom dia perdi todos os arquivos com extensão java só ficaram os arquivos com extensão .classe será que esses arquivos .classe tem alguma utilidade ou tenho recomeçar o meu projecto..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia tentar usar um [editor bytecode](http://set.ee/jbe/) ou [java decompiler](http://java-decompiler.github.io/), mas vai depender do seu conhecimento para reverter tudo. Se o projeto nao for muito grande, recomendaria comecar do zero e usar um método de controle de versao como o GIT por exemplo para evitar coisas desse tipo e outras mais.